# Magento 2 does not read my requirejs-config.js

Tags: magento2, html, customer-address, requirejs

I'm customizing customer address tab in Admin Panel. Here is my code. It's reading my files but 'Add New Addresses' button is not responding.

**my code is:**

**app/code/Learning/Helloworld/view/adminhtml/requirejs-config.js**

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/collection':'Learning_Helloworld/js/form/components/collection'
        }
    }
};
```

**app/code/Learning/Helloworld/view/adminhtml/web/js/form/components/collection.js**

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
define([
    'underscore',
    'mageUtils',
    'uiRegistry',
    'uiComponent',
    'uiLayout',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm'
], function (_, utils, registry, Component, layout, confirm) {
    'use strict';

    var childTemplate = {
        parent: '${ $.$data.name }',
        name: '${ $.$data.childIndex }',
        dataScope: '${ $.name }',
        nodeTemplate: '${ $.$data.name }.${ $.$data.itemTemplate }'
    };

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            lastIndex: 0,
            template: 'Learning_Helloworld/form/components/collection'
        },
..........................
    });
});
```

**app/code/Learning/Helloworld/view/adminhtml/web/template/form/components/collection.html**

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<div class="ui-tabs">
    <ul class="address-list ui-tabs-nav">
        <h1>Magento 2</h1>
        <!-- ko foreach: { data: element.elems, as: 'element' } -->
        <li class="address-list-item" data-bind="css: { 'ui-state-active': element.active }, click: activate">
            <div class="address-list-item-actions">
                <button class="action-delete" type="button" data-bind="click: $parent.removeAddress.bind($parent, element)">
                    <span data-bind="text: $parent.removeLabel"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <!-- ko template: previewTpl --><!-- /ko -->
            <div data-bind="foreach: { data:  element.getRegion('head'), as: 'element' }">
                <!-- ko template: element.getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            </div>
        </li>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <li class="address-list-actions last">
            <button data-bind="click: element.addChild" type="button" class="scalable add">
                <span data-bind="text: element.addLabel"></span>
            </button>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- ko foreach: { data: element.elems, as: 'element' } -->
    <div class="address-item-edit" data-bind="visible: element.active">
        <div class="address-item-edit-content">
            <fieldset class="admin__fieldset">
                <legend class="admin__legend">
                    <span data-bind="text: $parent.label"></span>
                </legend>
                <br>
                <!-- ko foreach: { data: element.getRegion('body'), as: 'element' } -->
                <!-- ko template: element.getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

After I have ran below commands

```
php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

'Add New Addresses' button is not responding in 'Addresses' tab. Where went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the below code

***app/code/Learning/Helloworld/view/base/requirejs-config.js***

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/collection':'Learning_Helloworld/js/form/components/collection'
        }
    }
};
```

***app/code/Learning/Helloworld/view/base/web/js/form/components/collection.js***

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
define([
    'underscore',
    'mageUtils',
    'uiRegistry',
    'uiComponent',
    'uiLayout',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm'
], function (_, utils, registry, Component, layout, confirm) {
    'use strict';

    var childTemplate = {
        parent: '${ $.$data.name }',
        name: '${ $.$data.childIndex }',
        dataScope: '${ $.name }',
        nodeTemplate: '${ $.$data.name }.${ $.$data.itemTemplate }'
    };

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            lastIndex: 0,
            template: 'Learning_Helloworld/form/components/collection'
        },
..........................
    });
});
```

***app/code/Learning/Helloworld/view/base/web/template/form/components/collection.html***

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<div class="ui-tabs">
    <ul class="address-list ui-tabs-nav">
        <h1>Magento 2</h1>
        <!-- ko foreach: { data: element.elems, as: 'element' } -->
        <li class="address-list-item" data-bind="css: { 'ui-state-active': element.active }, click: activate">
            <div class="address-list-item-actions">
                <button class="action-delete" type="button" data-bind="click: $parent.removeAddress.bind($parent, element)">
                    <span data-bind="text: $parent.removeLabel"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <!-- ko template: previewTpl --><!-- /ko -->
            <div data-bind="foreach: { data:  element.getRegion('head'), as: 'element' }">
                <!-- ko template: element.getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            </div>
        </li>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <li class="address-list-actions last">
            <button data-bind="click: element.addChild" type="button" class="scalable add">
                <span data-bind="text: element.addLabel"></span>
            </button>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- ko foreach: { data: element.elems, as: 'element' } -->
    <div class="address-item-edit" data-bind="visible: element.active">
        <div class="address-item-edit-content">
            <fieldset class="admin__fieldset">
                <legend class="admin__legend">
                    <span data-bind="text: $parent.label"></span>
                </legend>
                <br>
                <!-- ko foreach: { data: element.getRegion('body'), as: 'element' } -->
                <!-- ko template: element.getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

after that execute the below commands in `CLI`

```
php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Please let me know if it is not working.

happy coding!!!!!!.

Comment: I will back after I tried

Comment: not showing my content.

Comment: @ManojKumar, see updated my answer.

Comment: So.. basically you changed the adminhtml folder to base folder, right?