# Override Magento 2 JS file via requirejs-config.js not working

Tags: magento2, javascript, overrides, requirejs

I'm trying to override the file **vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/js/price-box.js** in my theme using **requirejs-config.js** unsuccessfully.

Location of my requirejs-config.js:

> app/design/frontend/Mytheme/mytheme/requirejs-config.js

Contents of my requirejs-config.js file:

```
var config = {
map: {
     '*': {
            priceBox:'js/price-box',
     }
}
};
```

I placed my new file price-box.js in here:

> app/design/frontend/Mytheme/mytheme/web/js/price-box.js

I also tried placing it under:

> app/design/frontend/Mytheme/mytheme/Magento_Catalog/web/js/price-box.js

but none of those worked.

In the frontend the file that gets loaded is:

> pub/static/frontend/Mytheme/mytheme/en_US/Magento_Catalog/js/price-box.js

Which is the default vendor file, and not mine? My file is here:

> pub/static/frontend/Mytheme/mytheme/en_US/js/price-box.js

We are working in **Developer mode** and **Cached Disabled**.

I tried a few commands to see if that would actually help:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Any suggestions?

Related questions:

1. [Magento2: How can I override core js module price-box.js](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112102/magento2-how-can-i-override-core-js-module-price-box-js)
2. [How to extend js class/method of checkout model class in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92396/how-to-extend-js-class-method-of-checkout-model-class-in-magento-2)
3. [Magento 2 does not read my requirejs-config.js](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109006/magento-2-does-not-read-my-requirejs-config-js)

Official documentation:

- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html

---

**Update 1**

Following suggestions of a StackExchange user I just did:

1. Move requirejs-config.js inside the web/ folder of my theme.
2. Manually remove everything under /pub/static/ except the .htaccess file
3. Execute this command: `php bin/magento dev:source-theme:deploy`

It didn't do any effects, the loaded file keeps being:

> pub/static/frontend/Mytheme/mytheme/en_US/Magento_Catalog/js/price-box.js

---

**Update 2 - Solution**

As suggested by David Verholen I did the following steps:

1. Remove the `map` from the requirejs-config.js file in the root folder of my theme.
2. Place my new files `price-box.js` in:

   > app/design/frontend/Mytheme/mytheme/Magento_Catalog/web/js/price-box.js
3. Manually remove all the contents from `/pub/static/` by doing:

   > rm -rf pub/static/*

Comment: Sorry, I had a brain fail and was incorrect: it is indeed supposed to be directly inside the theme folder. I suggest referencing the file directly. So instead of `priceBox:` try: `'Magento_Catalog/js/price-box':`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

placing the file under `app/design/frontend/Mytheme/mytheme/Magento_Catalog/web/js/price-box.js` should be sufficient (without any require config) to overload the file in your theme.

As already said, try clearing the pub/static/ folder content (except the .htaccess). On unix systems you can do this with the command `rm -rf pub/static/*` from the root directory since * does not include any files starting with a `.`

If this does not work, I assume there is a problem, since the original File is located in the `base` area while your theme is in the `frontend` area. Logically (if this is not working), since base should be inherited by all areas, this might be a bug in the overloading mechanism.

Comment: David one thing is noticeable in your answer that if js falls in the base directory then it may cause problem. Is there any way to fix this. In my case js is in base directory so i am not able to override it with my custom module.

Answer (score 1):

Contents of `requirejs-config.js` should be:

```
 var config = {
     map: {
         '*': {
             'Magento_Catalog/js/price-box':'Vendor_Module/js/price-box'
         }
     }
 };
```

Tested in Magento 2.1.4.

Comment: Not working. Help me with this -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/305247/how-to-override-3rd-party-module-requirejs-config-js-film-in-my-custom-module