# How to create new js file and override the one from extension - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript

So, I have a js file from an extension, that I need to override

the path is:  `app/code/MyExtension/MyExtensionSubfolder/view/frontend/web/js/script.js`

Where should I put the new JS file so that it will override `script.js` from above? And what else is necessary for this to work?

If I want to override a .phtml file from this extension, is simple. Create a new folder in
`app/code/design/frontend/Venustheme/kasitoo` with the name combined `MyExtension_MyExtensionSubfolder` and then follow the path from an extension and put here the phtml and it works.

But for js file from example if I create a new js file called script.js to the path
`app/code/design/frontend/Venustheme/kasitoo/MyExtension_MyExtensionSubfolder/web/js/script.js` is not working.

**So the question is where should I put my new JS file with the modifications I made, that will override the `script.js` from the extension. Because if I made the changes directly in the extension, after the first update of the extension, I will lose those changes.**

Answer (score 0):

I thought that would have worked, have you run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` or however you are currently managing symlinks? Also clear browser cache and delete `pub/static/frontend`. See [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156450/override-magento-2-js-file-via-requirejs-config-js-not-working?rq=1) for more info.

#### If that still doesn't work:

If that still doesn't work you can use the Require JS config to do this.

Create or modify `app/design/frontend/yourStore/yourTheme/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
  "map": {
    "*": {
      "oldScriptAliasOrPath": "newScriptAliasOrPath",
      "MyExtension_MyExtensionSubfolder/js/script": "js/myExtensionCustom/script",
    }
  }
};
```

First one is a generic example and the second one is using your file as an example. Using this method means your JS file would be placed in `app/design/frontend/yourStore/yourTheme/web/js/myExtensionCustom/script.js`.

I've done it that way based off the dev docs example, I hope you will be able to do this and keep the JS file in the same file structure but I'm not sure how.

Using `"MyExtension_MyExtensionSubfolder/js/script": "js/myExtensionCustom/script"` may work but I can't test it at the moment.

Related dev docs page - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html